# Is it possible to save table data into another macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Does macro programming allow to read data from a table and hardcode it into another macro?

Situation is that I want to read all data from a worksheet with a macro. I then want to save that data without the help of an additional program to another macro so I can delete the table, restart my pc and still be able to retrieve all data from my macro.

Comment: Yes you could but VBA would be an extraordinarily inefficient way to store a worksheet.

Comment: Would saving it in a .csv file in a designated location on your computer which can be dynamically saved and retrieved from the macro be a viable solution? 1) Save the table as a CSV file in a special TEMP folder you designate for your macros. 2) Retrieve that same CSV file with your macro.

Comment: No data other than macros and the actual excel worksheet are allowed. Is it possible to create a macro through a macro?

Comment: What exactly do you want to "hard code" into the new macro? Creating a macro through a macro only sounds useful for malicious code. I think there may be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: The idea is that I have data in my worksheet 1. Let's say A1 contains A and A2 contains B. My initial idea was to write a macro that creates another macro that has a function to populate cells A1 and A2 with the values A and B. By hard code I meant that variables are not stored through PC restarts (right?). So I have to write the cell values as they are inside the code of macro 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can "create a macro through a macro" (OPs words)  through the VBIDE.

To so so, add a reference to *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility*.  You can then write code to read and write to your VBA application.  You will also need to set *Trust access to the VBA project object model* in the trust Center.

That said, there may be better ways to achieve what you want, eg

1. Hide the sheet using `xlSheetVeryHidden` so it's only accessable from VBA
2. Write the data to one or more hidden `Names`
3. If you are using *.xlsm*, these documents can also contain custom XML parts, which you can use to store arbitrary XML data in the documents.  MSDN refrence: [Custom Xml Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608618%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Are your three options still available when the workbook is deleted?

Comment: Your data must be stored _somewhere_. All three options are applicable to some workbook, be it the original source book, the book containing the code, or some other book.  Where do you want to store the data?